# in golang what does the [:] syntax differ from the array assignment?

Tags: arrays, go, slice

I am currently going through the GoLang tutorials and have the following doubt.

```
arr1:=[...]int{1,2,3}
arr2:=arr1
arr1[1]=99
fmt.Println(arr1)
fmt.Println(arr2)
```

it outputs the following statements

```
[1 99 3]
[1 2 3]
```

> here only array a is modified, which makes sense as an array is treated as values.

if I try following things get confusing

```
a:=[...]int{1,2,3}
b:=a[:]
a[1]=88
fmt.Println(a)
fmt.Println(b)
```

this results in printing

```
[1 88 3]
[1 88 3]
```

Question: does this mean saying `b:=a` creates a copy of the array and saying `b:=a[:]` will create a slice that will point to the underlying array ('a' in this case)?

Comment: https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Slicing does not copy the slice's data. It creates a new slice value
> that points to the original array. This makes slice operations as
> efficient as manipulating array indices. Therefore, modifying the
> elements (not the slice itself) of a re-slice modifies the elements of
> the original slice

https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro

Check above link for internal structure behind Slice